# Merge two JavaScript Objects, add numbers instead of replacing them

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to merge two objects together. Numbers should not be replaced, but added.

If I use the spread operator, numbers are replaced.

How it works for the moment:

```
let obj1 = { title: 'Number', num: 1 }
let obj2 = { title: 'Number', num: 2 }

let merge = { ...obj1, ...obj2 }
// Object { title: 'Number', num: 2 }
```

How it should work:

```
let obj1 = { title: 'Number', num: 1 }
let obj2 = { title: 'Number', num: 2 }

let merge = { ...obj1, ...obj2 }
// Object { title: 'Number', num: 3 }
```

In the end the number should be added to each other instead of being replaced.
Is this possible with the spreach syntax?

Comment: No, spread operator will always overwrite any duplicatie properties it encounters. You could (for example) write a custom `reduce` function to achieve this though.

Comment: A simple way would be something like `{ ...obj1, ...obj2, num: obj1.num + obj2.num }`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the sum easily enough using `Array.reduce()`, we create an array containing the objects to be merged, then reduce to get the result:

```js
let obj1 = { title: 'Number', num: 1 }
let obj2 = { title: 'Number', num: 2 }

let a = [obj1, obj2];

const result = a.reduce ((acc, cur) =>  { 
    return { ...cur, num: (acc.num || 0) + cur.num};
}, {});

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can try something like this

```
    let obj1 = { title: 'Number', num: 1 }
    let obj2 = { title: 'Number', num: 2 }
  
    const obj = {};
    obj['title'] = obj1['title']
    obj['num'] = obj1['num'] + obj2['num']

    console.log(obj)
```